# How to prevent Mail.app to update address book on its own?

Tags: mail.app, contacts

Now that the iCloud works (almost) flawlessly on both my MacBook Pro and iPhone I get annoyed by Mail.app on my Mac which seems to update contacts in my address book on its own, without my request or approval. I can't seem to find any setting to switch this behaviour off.

As clever as it may be (and it seems to be, as it does update correct contacts with valid information), I don't want it. Here's why... I prefer to keep some contacts in my address book with nicknames only. Since address book doesn't consider nickname as a name when sorting, contacts with no first/last name end up and the end of the address book as unnamed. What I do is I put the nickname as the first name. And that works flawlessly. But whenever I reply to an email from a person that exists in my address book as a first-name-is-nickname it updates the contact information with the last name based on the From/Reply-To header in the email.

How do I prevent this?

-- edit --

No solutions here so far so I've posted [the same question on Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3457485).

Comment: Are you sure about changed address book entries? Or are you looking at the lost of recent receivers?

Comment: I am 100% positive it does change address book entries as they almost immediately sync with my iPhone. This hasn't happened before I set up iCloud, but I am now not able to say wether it's the iCloud or OS X 10.7.2 that changed this behaviour.

Comment: The same happens to me. For example my girlfriend is saved without surname but every time I wrote her an email the address book is changed. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution to the problem is to prevent Mail.app from tracking Previous Recipients. To permanently disable this feature you have to use this terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail SuppressAddressHistory -bool true
```

Once you've done that, make sure you delete your Previous Recipients history. To do this, in Mail.app, open up Previous Recipients window (Windows > Previous Recipients), select all existing records present there and hit "Remove From List".

From now on, your Address Book will not get updated by Mail.app.

***Note**, that this will change the way address autocompletion works in Mail.app. From now on only addresses present in your Address Book (and optionally in LDAP if configured) will be auto-completed. Previous Recipients which are not present in your Address Book will not be auto-completed.*

The whole problem seems to be quite unusual for Apple standards. A hidden and undocumented sync feature, with no obvious way to disable.